# Positioning images with CSS (fighting default boxes/white space)

Tags: html, css, image

I have 9 images on a page, the first 6 are fine, but the last 3 are down too low and need to be lifted up so they are level with the middle ones (images 4-6), see image for clarification.

http://s29.postimg.org/5jejyjgrr/tiles.jpg

The CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

header img {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

nav img {
  display: block;
}

div img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Space Shots</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/purple-space.jpg" alt="purple space" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/red-space2.jpg" alt="red space 2" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/blue-space3.jpg" alt="blue space3" height="250" width="250">
    <br><br><br><br>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/purple-space3.jpg" alt="purple space 3" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/red-space.jpg" alt="red space" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/blue-space.jpg" alt="blue space" height="250" width="250">
  </nav>
  <div>
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/blue-space2.jpg" alt="blue space 2" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/red-space3.jpg" alt="red space 3" height="250" width="250">
    <img src="/images/spaceshots/purple-space2.jpg" alt="purple space 2" height="250" width="250">
  </div>
</body>

<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type of a layout which you're trying to create, you will need to use `float: left` and `float: right` for your `nav` and `div` respectively. Here's a demo (view as full page):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
header img {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
nav img {
  display: block;
}
div img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="purple space" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="red space 2" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="blue space3" height="250" width="250">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</header>
<nav>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="purple space 3" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="red space" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="blue space" height="250" width="250">
</nav>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="blue space 2" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="red space 3" height="250" width="250">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="purple space 2" height="250" width="250">
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1ebxh92o/1/embedded/result/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Make a little change to your css
add a float: left; to nav

```
nav img {
  display: block;
  float:left
}
```

also create a css for div

```
div{
  float:right;
}
```

Refresh Your Page!
Done!